# Vue: Data 'undefind' when component render

Tags: vue.js

I would like to set a class to one of my elements when current language I equal to element id. But when `method` is fired to do this check then I have log "undefined".

Why? How to set that class properly?

Is data object loaded latter then component render?

```html
<template>
   <div>
       <div class="star-box">
            <div class="head">
                <img :src="'images/flags/en.png'"
                     id="en"
                     class="student-img"
                     v-bind:class="{'activeLanguage': checkActiveLanguage('en')}"
                     alt=""
                   >
                </div>
                <div class="body">
                     <h5 class="heading">English</h5>
                </div>
         </div> 
         <div class="star-box">
              <div class="head">
                    <img :src="'images/flags/de.png'"
                        id="de"
                        class="student-img"
                        v-bind:class="{'activeLanguage': checkActiveLanguage('de')}"
                        alt=""
                     >
               </div>
               <div class="body">
                     <h5 class="heading">Deutsch</h5>
                </div>
         </div>
   </div>
</template>
```

**JS**

```js
<script>
    import {mapActions,mapGetters} from 'vuex';

    export default {
        name: 'Language',
        data() {
            return {
                language: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            checkActiveLanguage: (lang)=> {
                console.log(this.language);
                if(lang==this.language) return true;
            },
            ...mapGetters(['getCurrentLanguage']),

        },
        beforeMount(){
            this.language =  this.getCurrentLanguage();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: please share any fiddle so that we can reproduce.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fpw40bju/#&togetherjs=DI6b9tMol5

Comment: your `mapGetters` should be at `computed`?

Comment: Could you please provide code of your store? Is `getCurrentLanguage` actually defined as getter in store? Because you use it as `action`, and probably you need to use `mapActions` instead of `mapGetters`